# How to return two tables in T-SQL using stored procedure or functions?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures, return-value

I have property details and I want vacant property & occupied separately in two different table as a return result. Kindly let me know is it possible to return 2 tables, as a result, using stored procedure or functions?

```
CREATE FUNCTION PropInfo (@OWnerId INT)
RETURNS @Occupied TABLE 
                  (
                      OwnerId INT,
                      PropertyId INT, 
                      TenantId INT, 
                      PropertyName VARCHAR
                  )
AS
BEGIN
    IF TenantProperty.IsActive = 1
        INSERT INTO @Occupied
            SELECT 
                OwnerId, Property.Id AS PropertyId, 
                TenantProperty.Id AS TenantId, Name AS PropertyName
            FROM 
                Owners 
            INNER JOIN
                OwnerProperty ON Owners.Id = OwnerProperty.OwnerId
            INNER JOIN 
                Property ON OwnerProperty.PropertyId = Property.Id
            INNER JOIN 
                TenantProperty ON Property.Id = TenantProperty.PropertyId
            WHERE 
                OwnerId = @OwnerId

RETURNS @Vacant TABLE 
                (
                    OwnerId INT, 
                    PropertyId INT,  
                    TenantId INT, 
                    PropertyName VARCHAR
                )

IF TenantProperty.IsActive = 0 OR TenantProperty.IsActive IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Vacant
        SELECT 
            OwnerId, Property.Id AS PropertyId, 
            TenantProperty.Id AS TenantId, Name AS PropertyName
        FROM 
            Owners 
        INNER JOIN
            OwnerProperty ON Owners.Id = OwnerProperty.OwnerId
        INNER JOIN 
            Property ON OwnerProperty.PropertyId = Property.Id
        INNER JOIN 
            TenantProperty ON Property.Id = TenantProperty.PropertyId
        WHERE 
            OwnerId = @OwnerId
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: A _function_ has a single return value (or table). A stored procedure can return values in `output` parameters, an exit value (expected to provide a status) and multiple result sets. See Example B [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#Examples). Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. If you omit a length declaration, the length defaults to **1 character** - typically not what you want. Also: you could **easily** merge this into a single table to be returned, by adding a flag `Vacant BIT` and setting it appropriately

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve more than one result set from a stored procedure. Try the following.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc](
    @param int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM OWNERS
    SELECT * FROM PROPERTY
END
```

When you do `dbo.sproc 1`, you'll get two result sets back. One for OWNERS and one for PROPERTY.

If you want to OUTPUT two table types from a stored procedure, that's a separate question that will need a separate solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, we have to use multiple SELECT statements to return multiple result sets. And it's not possible to return more than 1 table, as a result, using stored procedure but we can create tables and we can insert values in it.